MQL4 Errors for OnCalculate function
I am hoping you can help fix my code. I am trying to code a MT4 indicator to indicate a powerful downward bar.
No matter what I do, I still get :1 errors, 1 warnings
OnCalculate function declared with wrong type or/and parameters line 42 column6
OnCalculate function not found in custom indicator line 1 column 1
Any suggestions?
Thanks!!!
#property strict

// Define indicator buffers
#property indicator_chart_window
#property indicator_buffers 3
#property indicator_color1 Blue
#property indicator_color2 Red
#property indicator_color3 Lime

// Define indicator labels
#property indicator_label1 "Doji"
#property indicator_label2 "Exhaustion"
#property indicator_label3 "Engulfing"

// Declare indicator buffers
double DojiBuffer[];
double ExhaustionBuffer[];
double EngulfingBuffer[];

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator initialization function                         |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
  {
   // Set buffer arrays
   SetIndexBuffer(0, DojiBuffer);
   SetIndexBuffer(1, ExhaustionBuffer);
   SetIndexBuffer(2, EngulfingBuffer);
   
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator iteration function                              |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
                 const int prev_calculated,
                 const datetime &time[],
                 const double &open[],
                 const double &high[],
                 const double &low[],
                 const double &close[],
                 const long &tick_volume[],
                 const int &spread[])
  {
   int i;
   for(i = prev_calculated; i < rates_total; i++)
     {
      // Calculate candle range
      double candle_range = high[i] - low[i];

      // Calculate upper shadow length
      double upper_shadow = high[i] - MathMax(open[i], close[i]);

      // Calculate lower shadow length
      double lower_shadow = MathMin(open[i], close[i]) - low[i];

      // Check for Doji candle condition
      if (candle_range > 0 && upper_shadow < 0.05 * candle_range && lower_shadow < 0.05 * candle_range) {
          DojiBuffer[i] = low[i];
      } else {
          DojiBuffer[i] = EMPTY_VALUE;
      }
      
      // Check for Exhaustion candle condition
      if (i > 0 && candle_range > 2 * MathAbs(close[i] - close[i - 1]) && upper_shadow < 0.15 * candle_range && lower_shadow < 0.15 * candle_range) {
          ExhaustionBuffer[i] = low[i];
      } else {
          ExhaustionBuffer[i] = EMPTY_VALUE;
      }
      
      // Check for Engulfing candle condition
      if (i > 0 && close[i] > open[i] && open[i - 1] > close[i - 1] && close[i] > open[i - 1] && open[i] < close[i - 1] && (close[i] - open[i]) > 0.9 * (high[i] - low[i]) && (open[i - 1] - close[i - 1]) > 0.9 * (high[i - 1] - low[i - 1])) {
          EngulfingBuffer[i] = low[i];
      } else {
          EngulfingBuffer[i] = EMPTY_VALUE;
      }
     }
  }


int OnCalculate( should help.
It is okay if you do not need any result, but the function should meet the requirements in order to be recognized by compiler. so you can add return(rates_total); after loop is over.

I've done this before but had the same errors

Show min compiled verified example (MCVE) to go further

also need to add const long& volume[], after tick_volume (but easier to copy whole function signiture from a working indicator, e.g. MA
